developing and deploying azure functions locally using VS code
I'm trying to develop and deploy my http trigger locally from visual code studio for the past 2 days I'm able to do this but suddenly my http trigger function gone in azure portal and also not visible in VS code workspace when I try to start to debug. I'm getting following error.

Function code:

    import azure.functions as func
    from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
    from azure.iot.device import IoTHubDeviceClient, Message
    import crc32c
    import base64
     
    def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
        # Retrieve the blob name from the HTTP request
        blob_name = req.params.get('blob_name')
        if not blob_name:
            return func.HttpResponse(
                "Please provide a 'blob_name' parameter in the query string.",
                status_code=400
            )
     
        # Connect to Azure Blob Storage
        blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string("blob connection string")
        blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container="blob-device", blob=blob_name)
     
        try:
            # Download the blob
            blob_data = blob_client.download_blob()
            binary_data = blob_data.readall()
     
            # Send the binary file to the device (pseudo-code)
            send_to_device(binary_data)
     
            return func.HttpResponse("Binary file sent to the device successfully.", status_code=200)
     
        except Exception as e:
            return func.HttpResponse(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}", status_code=500)
     
    def send_to_device(binary_data):
        # Calculate CRC32 checksum of the binary data
        crc32_checksum = crc32c.crc32(binary_data)
     
        # Convert binary data to base64 for transmission
        # encoded_data = base64.b64encode(binary_data)
     
        # Connect to IoT Hub
        conn_str = "Iot Hub connect string"
        device_client = IoTHubDeviceClient.create_from_connection_string(conn_str)
     
        try:
            # Connect to the IoT Hub
            device_client.connect()
     
            # Send the binary file along with CRC32 checksum as a message to IoT Hub
            msg = {
                "file": binary_data,
                "checksum": crc32_checksum
            }
            device_client.send_message(msg)
     
            print("Binary file sent to IoT Hub successfully.")
           
            # Receive acknowledgment or any other messages from IoT Hub
            while True:
                message = device_client.receive_message()
                if message:
                    print("Received message from IoT Hub:")
                    print(message.data)
                    # Handle the received message here
                    # Example: If the message contains acknowledgment or status
                    # handle_message(message)
                else:
                    print("No more messages from IoT Hub.")
                    break
           
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred while sending data to IoT Hub: {e}")
        finally:
            # Disconnect from IoT Hub
            device_client.disconnect()

Update
I'm able deploy the code and I copy the function URL.
The following is the output I'm getting VS code and in browser


Updated code :
    import azure.functions as func
import logging
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from azure.iot.device import IoTHubDeviceClient, Message
import crc32c
import base64
import os
import json
import random
import sys
from azure.iot.hub import IoTHubRegistryManager
 
app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.route(route="http_trigger")
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    # Retrieve the blob name from the HTTP request
    blob_name = req.params.get('blob_name')
    if not blob_name:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "Please provide a 'blob_name' parameter in the query string.",
            status_code=400
        )
 
    # Connect to Azure Blob Storage
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=otastorage;AccountKey=5dCDeZPLUtEb5ucDZbJT8gosEB3P6LK92D4HRW244SnUU1xsgWDTfClJNVhLDonZ9cChAa8phO8+AStvBUT/w==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net")
    blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container="blob-device", blob=blob_name)
 
    try:
        # Download the blob
        blob_data = blob_client.download_blob()
        binary_data = blob_data.readall()
 
        # Send the binary file to the device (pseudo-code)
        send_to_device(binary_data)
 
        return func.HttpResponse("Binary file sent to the device successfully.", status_code=200)
 
    except Exception as e:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}", status_code=500)
 
def send_to_device(binary_data):
    # Calculate CRC32 checksum of the binary data
    crc32_checksum = crc32c.crc32(binary_data)
 
    # Convert binary data to base64 for transmission
    # encoded_data = base64.b64encode(binary_data)
 
    # Connect to IoT Hub
    CONNECTION_STRING = "HostName=iothub.azure-devices.net;SharedAccessKeyName=service;SharedAccessKey=MmjcbQ0RCmuIK/JfGO28odyxCf9ZN7TL8AIoTHrJNvA="
    DEVICE_ID = "OTA-Device"
 
    try:
        # Create IoTHubRegistryManager
        registry_manager = IoTHubRegistryManager(CONNECTION_STRING)

        '''props={}
        # optional: assign system properties
        props.update(messageId = "message_%d" % i)
        props.update(correlationId = "correlation_%d" % i)
        props.update(contentType = "application/json")'''

        msg_body = {
            "file": base64.b64encode(binary_data).decode(),
            "checksum": crc32_checksum
        }
        msg = Message(json.dumps(msg_body))

        registry_manager.send_c2d_message(DEVICE_ID, msg)
    except Exception as ex:
        print ( "Unexpected error {0}" .format(ex) )
        return

The trigger is happening but the following error is appearing.

Invoke Screenshot

Updated Receive program python
import time
from azure.iot.device import IoTHubDeviceClient

RECEIVED_MESSAGES = 0

CONNECTION_STRING = "HostName=iothub.azure-devices.net;DeviceId=MCU;SharedAccessKey=pOkHxKaDejoJUSgUU3ZdmKqG/KV3XOcbgILSX8tDiMk="


def message_handler(message):
    global RECEIVED_MESSAGES
    RECEIVED_MESSAGES += 1
    print("")
    print("Message received:")

    # print data from both system and application (custom) properties
    for property in vars(message).items():
        print ("    {}".format(property))

    print("Total calls received: {}".format(RECEIVED_MESSAGES))
    
def main():
    print ("Starting the Python IoT Hub C2D Messaging device sample...")

    # Instantiate the client
    client = IoTHubDeviceClient.create_from_connection_string(CONNECTION_STRING, websockets=True)

    print ("Waiting for C2D messages, press Ctrl-C to exit")
    try:
        # Attach the handler to the client
        client.on_message_received = message_handler

        while True:
            time.sleep(1000)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("IoT Hub C2D Messaging device sample stopped")
    finally:
        # Graceful exit
        print("Shutting down IoT Hub Client")
        client.shutdown()
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


please share your function code

updated the code (Note; there is comment python ignore it)

What is your requirement? What do you want to achieve by using this code?

When the http trigger happens the function should read the bin file and send it to iothub. On short note OTA.

I have used the below code and it worked for me.
import azure.functions as func
import logging
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from azure.iot.device import IoTHubDeviceClient, Message
import crc32c
import base64
import os
import json

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.route(route="http_trigger")
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    blob_name = req.params.get('blob_name')
    if not blob_name:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "Please provide a 'blob_name' parameter in the query string.",
            status_code=400
        )
    else:
        # Connect to Azure Blob Storage
        blob_connect_str = os.environ["StorageAccountConnectionString"]
        blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(blob_connect_str)
        blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container="demo-container", blob=blob_name)

        try:
            # Download the blob
            blob_data = blob_client.download_blob()
            binary_data = blob_data.readall()
            # Send the binary file to the device (pseudo-code)
            send_to_device(binary_data)

            return func.HttpResponse("Binary file sent to the device successfully.", status_code=200)

        except Exception as e:
            return func.HttpResponse(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}", status_code=500)

def send_to_device(binary_data):
    # Calculate CRC32 checksum of the binary data
    crc32_checksum = crc32c.crc32(binary_data)

    # Connect to IoT Hub
    iot_conn_str = os.environ["IotHubConnectionString"]
    device_client = IoTHubDeviceClient.create_from_connection_string(iot_conn_str)

    try:
        # Connect to the IoT Hub
        device_client.connect()

        # Send the binary file along with CRC32 checksum as a message to IoT Hub
        msg_body = {
            "file": base64.b64encode(binary_data).decode(),
            "checksum": crc32_checksum
        }
        msg = Message(json.dumps(msg_body))
        device_client.send_message(msg)

        print("Binary file sent to IoT Hub successfully.")

        # Receive acknowledgment or any other messages from IoT Hub
        while True:
            message = device_client.receive_message()
            if message is None:
                continue
            print("Received message from IoT Hub:")
            print(message.data)
            break

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while sending data to IoT Hub: {e}")
    finally:
            # Disconnect from IoT Hub
            device_client.disconnect() 

I have declared the connection strings in local settings file.
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing",
    "StorageAccountConnectionString": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=afrinstore01;AccountKey=cRWkgd************==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "IotHubConnectionString": "HostName={HostName}.azure-devices.net;DeviceId={deviceId};SharedAccessKey=3Rj*********k="
  }
}

requirements.txt-
azure-functions
azure-storage-blob
azure-iot-device
crc32c

I am able to send the message to Azure Iot Hub.

Below code used IoTHubRegistryManager to send a message from Storage account.
import azure.functions as func
import logging
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import crc32c
import base64
import os
import json
from azure.iot.hub import IoTHubRegistryManager
 
app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.route(route="http_trigger")
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    # Retrieve the blob name from the HTTP request
    blob_name = req.params.get('blob_name')
    if not blob_name:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "Please provide a 'blob_name' parameter in the query string.",
            status_code=400
        )
    else:
        # Connect to Azure Blob Storage
        blob_connect_str = os.environ["StorageAccountConnectionString"]
        blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(blob_connect_str)
        blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container="demo-container", blob=blob_name)
 
        try:
            # Download the blob
            blob_data = blob_client.download_blob()
            binary_data = blob_data.readall()
 
            # Send the binary file to the device (pseudo-code)
            send_to_device(binary_data)
 
            return func.HttpResponse("Binary file sent to the device successfully.", status_code=200)
 
        except Exception as e:
            return func.HttpResponse(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}", status_code=500)
 
def send_to_device(binary_data):
    # Calculate CRC32 checksum of the binary data
    crc32_checksum = crc32c.crc32(binary_data)
 
    # Connect to IoT Hub
    CONNECTION_STRING = "{IOT_connection_string}"
    DEVICE_ID = "{deviceId}"
    
    try:
        
        # Create IoTHubRegistryManager
        registry_manager = IoTHubRegistryManager.from_connection_string(CONNECTION_STRING)

        msg_body = {
            "file": base64.b64encode(binary_data).decode(),
            "checksum": crc32_checksum
        }
        msg = json.dumps(msg_body)
        registry_manager.send_c2d_message(DEVICE_ID, msg)
        
    except Exception as ex:
        print ( "Unexpected error {0}" .format(ex) )
        return


I tried and able to successfully deploy but some issues I'm getting updated above

@sai Your Url should look like this http://localhost:7071/api/http_trigger?blob_name={pass the blob name present in the container with extension}

yes did , It triggered but in browser I'm getting this -
An error occurred  "DeviceId"

@sai you need to pass the iot hub connection string in this format HostName={HostName}.azure-devices.net;DeviceId={deviceId};SharedAccessKey=3Rj*********k=

what connection string should I use, I used iothubowner connection string

@sai Click on Device--> click on the IOT Hub device --> Then fetch the primary connection string

Getting the below error
-An error occurred while sending data to IoT Hub: Could not connect to IoTHub.
Also tried with websockets (443 port). In connect function I used connect(websockets = True).

Are you using my code and also Is IOT connection string correct? It looks like a connection establishment error

trying both changed the connection string accordingly

@sai If your connection string is not correct then only you will get connection error

using the same connection string I am able to send data using python code not related to trigger a separate one

Can you share the code which worked for you without trigger?

Hi, I changed the sending part code in my program due to Iothub device properties limit. Yes, At a time only one device is able to connect so I used C2D program instead of the above one will share the code

@sai were you able to get the output?

nope, I updated the code

@sai please share a screenshot of how you are invoking your function

@sai added modified code for IoTHubRegistryManager please check

Yes will check now Should I use hub->devices->device connection string or Hub->shared access policy -> service connection string
(Note : why service connection I asked means the receive side is already connected to that particular device )

You can use the normal one which is there in shared access policy

Getting this error "An error occurred: C2D message send failure" may be my daily limit of messages exceeded (showing in my azure portal) will try tomorrow and let you know

@sai were you able to get the expected response?

Hi @Afrin sorry for late reply Yes I'm able to send C2D messages. In receive side only I'm getting problem at first 2-3 times the receive received the bin file I sent but after multiple tries the receive program is connected and suddenly getting disconnected

updated the receive program

@sai please create a separate question as the initial requirement of this question has already been fulfilled
